# match_parent doesn't work with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

I use the Android Design Support Library (`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0`) and I have a `LinearLayout` in `CoordinatorLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#44ff44"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout> 

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_icon_tint_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_text_color"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />
```

In the code I have changed the background colour and I expect the BG should fill all on the display (because I use match_parent in layout_width and layout_height) but I got the BG colour like this:

[image]

Look like it shows with `wrap_content` more than use `match_parent`.
I try to use `layout_weight` in LinearLayout and `layout_centerInParent` and it doesn't work also.

What I did wrong?. Or is it an API bug?

**Update**:**

To fulfil the background I can use `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` (Suggest by @Abdullah). But another my point for this question is I want the `match_parent`, `layout_weight` in LinearLayout or `layout_centerInParent` and other relative values in RelativeLayout to work properly under the `CoordinatorLayout`. Right now when I add fragment to the LinearLayout, the layout alignment (in fragment layout) is not same as my expectation. Everything that using ratio or relative value does not work.

Thank you

Comment: Try to add android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" to LinearLayout.

Comment: @Abdullah thank you for you answer.  Your suggest it work to full fill the background colour but the `layout_weight` (in LinearLayout) and `layout_centerInParent` (in relative layout) still not work properly.

Comment: You need to use "FrameLayout" where you adding fragment. not need to update in Fragment layout.

Comment: @Watcharin.s Might I know on how you fixed this?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` should be applied to a `View` that's implement [`ScrollingView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ScrollingView.html).

Remove the behavior if you don't need auto-hide of the `ToolbarLayout` when scrolling the main content or use a `RecyclerView` instead of the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Thank you for you help but I am not sure if you understand my point. My point is I want the `match_parent`,  `layout_weight ` in LinearLayout or `layout_centerInParent ` and other relative values in RelativeLayout to work properly under the `CoordinatorLayout `. Right now when I add fragment to the LinearLayout, the layout alignment is not same as my expectation. Everything that related with ratio or relative value does not work.

Comment: What about an setup where the above layout is the layout of the primary Activity with the toolbar as the "action bar" and instead of a LinearLayout the content view is a FrameLayout? The FrameLayout is then used as the container view for Fragments. If the Fragment contains a scrollable view like a RecyclerView the toolbar should scroll away, if not it should stay fixed. That's basically my setup but I also face the issue that the Fragments do not fill up the whole space although match_parent is declared.